# Command from console doesn't run when launched from sshj

Tags: java, linux, sshj

I launch a `jar` from the console and it runs fine:

```
nohup /usr/bin/java -jar payara-micro-5.183.jar myapp.war > log.out 2>&1 & echo $!
```

When I run the same command from a distant computer with `sshj`, it returns a pid but the process can't be seen in the console, and actually the process doesn't run. In both cases I log via ssh, public key, with the same user.

The code running the command via `sshj`:

```
try (Session session = sshClient.startSession()) {
    final Command cmd = session.exec("nohup /usr/bin/java -jar payara-micro-5.183.jar myapp.war > log.out 2>&1 & echo $!");
    String response = (IOUtils.readFully(cmd.getInputStream()).toString());
    // response shows a pid number
    cmd.join(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("\n** exit status: " + cmd.getExitStatus());
    //exit status is 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

- With a previous command, I had `cd`to the directory where the jar is situated.
- but this `cp` doesn't remove the need to **use full paths for files used in the commands run after**